# How to prevent to load load all data in this ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am practicing small example in Ajax. I wanted to update the update the selected option in the drop down list in the div#testID container. But it is loading the whole page in to the div
How can i prevent that. below the sample code that i have been using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<form acttion="" method="post" name="DispalyForm">
    Dispaly: <select name="SelectFilter" class="filter">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="testID">#SelectFilter#</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.filter').change(function() {
            $('form[name=DispalyForm]').submit();
        });
        $('form[name=DispalyForm]').submit(function(event) {
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url : window.location,
                type : "POST",
                data : data,
                dataType : "html",
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#testID').html(data);
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Filter `data` down to only your target element. `$(data).filter("targetel")` or `$(data).find("targetel")` with `.appendTo("#testID")`

Comment: Use #ID with an id of an element to load data from in url

Comment: You have a typo in your form: **form acttion=""** v. **form action=""**

Comment: @ Kevin B thank you very much for your quick reply. Can you please explain little bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure how i could explain it any more than that.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski That only works with the `.load` method.

Answer (score 0):

To practice ajax example, use some other file on the server side that returns you data. :

for example in "PHP" :
test.php  : This files check if the request is post, return the data of "SelectFilter".

```
  if ($_REQUEST['post']){
      echo $_REQUEST['SelectFilter']; 
  }
```

Your html file : - you basic html file

```
<form action="" method="post" name="DispalyForm">
    Display: <select name="SelectFilter" class="filter">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="testID">#SelectFilter#</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.filter').change(function() {
        $('form[name=DispalyForm]').submit();
    });
    $('form[name=DispalyForm]').submit(function(event) {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : "test.php
,
            type : "POST",
            data : data,
            dataType : "html",
            success : function(data) {
                $('#testID').html(data);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

One more thing currently you are doing, dataType as "html", so it is going to send you the complete page.  you can also use json for best practice to just get necessary data:

Example json :

```
 {
  "requestedValue": "test"
  }
```

In js, you just have to do :

```
  $('#testID').html(data.requestedValue);
```